# Google Compute Engine - Start GUI mode?

Tags: google-compute-engine

How can I get into the GUI mode on a Google Compute Engine instance? I've installed the "Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, amd64 xenial image built on 2016-09-07" instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux servers don't have a graphical interface by default. You need to connect to the server via SSH and use the command line interface. You can install the GUI on the server, but this is not really recommended.